# Current limiter for small 12V DC motor

Tags: current, motor, dc

I have a situation where a small DC motor is moving the flap from one side to the other. The flap can be in two positions but without limit switch. Change of position lasts about 3 seconds. The problem occurs when the motor reaches its position, but still has supply. After some time it can easily break gears. So I want to limit the current for the motor in at least one direction.

I have been thinking about this simple current limiter, but is it a problem when it gets reversed supply? Is it ok to solve it with one diode which will conduct most of the current in that situation?

[image]

Comment: Have you considered using a MOSFET to drive the motor with PWM?

Comment: I want to keep it simple and I can not change electronics that drives the motor.

Comment: Just to be sure: does the motor turn/run one way only or two ways? In the latter case you can not use the above circuit.

Comment: It turns in two ways. Is there some other solution? With two LM317 as current limiter, and two diodes maybe?

Comment: Is there a long pause between moving? (I am thinking of a PTC)

Comment: Yes, there is a long pause. When system starts it is trying to move the flap in direction which was already reached, that is the biggest problem.

Comment: Yes you could implement this for both low-side switches of an h-bridge driver. How are you driving your motor bipolar at present? Or one side of the h-bridge if you only care about Ipeak in one direction.

Comment: I can not get to the control unit, nor change anything there, the only option is to put something between the motor and its supply.

Comment: I am thinking of a protection circuit like yours above but placed within a bridge rectifier.

Comment: Can this be solution for one side current limiter?
 https://imgur.com/a/0L1Sa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry it is now past 1 AM here and I am getting tired. I just wanted to give you a heads-up what the idea was. The bridge rectifier makes sure that the current through the circuit always goes the same way, no matter which way the motor turns.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flOzpK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thank you, I didn't consider that a bridge rectifier can be used like this. This could be the solution.

Comment: What is D5 for?